# Python 2.7: How many bytes in utf-16 string, created with \U prefix?

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, utf-16

I want to use utf-16 in my app.

I know, that \u is for describing utf-8 character (2 bytes)

```
>>> u'\u1234'
> u'\u1234'
```

And \U for describing utf-16 characher (4 bytes).

```
>>> u'\U12345678'
> u'\5678'
```

Is there any constraints for long of character, describing in \U way?

Comment: The second line is a syntax error, as it doesn't define a valid Unicode code point.

Comment: uTF-8 and UTF-16 are not 2 resp 4 bytes; both have variable lengths up to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`\U` can only be used for valid Unicode codepoints:

```
>>> u'\U12345678'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-9: illegal Unicode character
>>> u'\U0001FFFF'
u'\U0001ffff'
```

Python 2 can handle these fine, but it depends on your build type (wide or narrow) how many characters this counts as. A narrow build uses two UTF-16 codepoints to encode the character.